# PHP не видит данные из HTML

Tags: php

Привет!
Написал запрос, но он не хочет брать данные из формы

```
<?php
$subject = "SEO Analyse Request!";
$url = $_GET["url_seo"];
$email = $_GET["email_seo"];
mail("christianciubuc@gmail.com", $subject, "Please Analyse My WebSite:\n" . $url, "From: $email\n");
echo "Thank you! We will reply soon!";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. He `$_GET`, a `$_POST`.
2. `..., "From: ".$email);`

Comment: Тоже самое:
Вот как я изменил код:
<?php
$subject = "SEO Analyse Request!";
$url = $_POST["url_seo"];
$email = $_POST["email_seo"];
mail("christianciubuc@gmail.com", $subject, "Please Analyse My WebSite:\n"  .$url, "From:" .$email);
echo "Thank you! We will reply soon!";
?>